# Elasticsearch terms with array of urls

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.5, below are the index on Elasticsearch

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "corpindex-qa",
        "_type" : "corpdocs-qa",
        "_id" : "5cb468fd35b9db6f2235e4c4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Edition" : {
            "Values" : {
              "title" : "new featured parallex"
          }
          },
          "url" : "/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex",
          "year" : 2019,
          "author" : "",
          "docdef" : "new-featured-parallex-reference-1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "corpindex-qa",
        "_type" : "corpdocs-qa",
        "_id" : "5ccfe1dd6948151485158661",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Edition" : {
            "Values" : {
              "title" : "demo of event careers",
              "description" : "careers"

            }
          },
          "url" : "/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card",
          "year" : 2019,
          "author" : "",
          "docdef" : "inline-event-card"
        }
      }]
```

Trying to get the documents by using query with terms on nodejs with elasticsearch client module.

```
client.search({
                            index: searchIndex,
                            type: searchType
                            , body: {
                                query: {
                                    terms: {
                                        "url": ["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

getting zero document while performing above.

```
{"took":0,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Here is the mapping details, which took it from elasticsaerch

```
{
corpindex-qa: {
aliases: { },
mappings: {
corpdocs-qa: {
properties: {
url: {
type: "text",
fields: {
keyword: {
type: "keyword",
ignore_above: 256
}
}
},
year: {
type: "long"
}
}
}
},
settings: {
index: {
creation_date: "1559900006341",
number_of_shards: "5",
number_of_replicas: "1",
uuid: "xL6PICFARZq6zMZBpm-75A",
version: {
created: "5050399"
},
provided_name: "corpindex-qa"
}
}
}
}
```

Please share your thoughts that would helpful to me.

Comment: you are missing `"filter"` after `query`

Comment: If I use 'filter' after query, getting this error.

{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filter]","line":1,"col":20}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no [query] registered for [filter]","line":1,"col":20},"status":400}

Comment: oops! in 5 that is deprecated. use this query. `{"query":{"bool":{"filter":{"terms":{"url":["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]}}}}}` using bool.

Comment: could you share your index mapping ?

Comment: Actually, I tried this but no use, getting same error. 'filter' option is deprecated in above v5.

Comment: tried this too query: {
                                    bool: {
                                        must: {
                                                terms: {
                                                    "url": ["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]
                                                }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
}

Getting none

Comment: @ahochstein index mapping have been added in question box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to match exact `url` use `url.keyword` instead of `url`. Update your query to below:

```
client.search({
                            index: searchIndex,
                            type: searchType
                            , body: {
                                query: {
                                    terms: {
                                        "url.keyword": ["/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex","/demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card"]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: yes, it is working. what's the reason behind? why do I we use url.keyword instead of 'url'

Comment: `text` field by default uses standard analyzer. This results in generation of tokens. `terms` don't apply analyzer and does the exact match. `url` has a subfield `keyword` whose data type is `keyword`, which store the exact input value as a single token. Therefore it matches.

Comment: one more thing that, I should get the results in order of URL ( first result set should be /demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-featured-parallex and then /demo-inline-component-capability/demo-of-event-card). now I am getting un-order list of url

Comment: The order of terms in a `terms` query doesn't effect the order documents in output. If you need to order based on terms, you have to handle it differently. If that is a requirement please log a separate question for it.

Comment: I have created a separate for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547396/elasticsearch-query-with-array-of-value